# How to run a npm script command by Node version that specified by nvm in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can run a script command by Node version that specified by nvm in VS Code's terminal.

[image]

But I run a script command on "npm script" panel directly，the Node version is not specified by nvm.

[image]

[image]

How to run npm script command by Node version that specified by nvm in VS Code?

I can't use `nvm alias default`, because this is the only project that needs to use the lower version of Node.

Comment: `nvm exec` will help?

Comment: Why not just keep using the terminal?